# Moodle - Site Adminstrator Block is missing

Tags: moodle, moodle-api, moodle-mobile

I am using moodle 3.4 Version.
My moodle is not showing Site administrator in "Add a Block".Due to which i am not able to add "Site administrator Block" on my Dashboard front page.

Can anyone please help me .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution after 2hours with Moodle 3.6 => If block settings is missing ... database: mdl_block_instances / blockname: settings | pagetypepattern: * (this will display settings on all pages)

Comment: Is this a question? Please write a question if you want an answer.

Comment: @Frank - thanks for posting, I updated this row with a configdata value of "*" and yet still don't have the Admin block showing anywhere. I'm on Moodle 3.10.6

Comment: The solution I eventually adopted was to just switch Themes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a Site admin and logging in with admin credentials (Site Administration block) comes by default. It's strange to hear that you are unable to find that block by default.

First- Check it with admin credentials it should be there by default.

Second - In "Add a Block"  you will find "Administration" block. check the image attached.

For further query, kindly come up with elaboration and screenshots, so that we can understand it better .

[image]